# Interest on a savings account with monthly deposit

Tags: excel, math

Hi all I'm writing an excel sheet for savings accounts and I need to know the amount that'll be in a savings account with interest compounded daily, but the account will also have a monthly deposit.

Without the monthly deposit it would just be:

```
=StartingBalance * (1 + Rate)^NumberOfDays
```

But I can't figure out how to add the deposit
Thanks!

Comment: Same thing + depositAmount * (1 + r) ^ NumberOfDaysFromTheDepositDay.

Comment: But what if its 6 months? That's 6 deposits. Do I just multiply the deposit amount by 6?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's a basic math calculation question, and there are thousands of sites available through a quick Google search that provide a solution. Sorry, but voting to close as "off-topic".

Comment: I taged it as excel and math...

Comment: @vbman11 you are in excel: one line per deposit + one column for the corresponding interest + a sum at the bottom. (That's one way).

Comment: I just didn't want to use a bunch of unneeded space when I can just use one formula

Comment: Adding a tag doesn't magically make it a programming question. :-) As I said, it's a basic math question, and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Initial payment + (deposit * months)) * (1 + rate) ^ (365 * (months / 12))

Comment: That assumes your monthly deposits are all made at the same date as the initial payment. Probably not what you expect...